# ¿Como saber cual es el proyecto abierto en localhost?

Tags: servidor, symfony3

Estoy siguiendo [el curso sobre Symfony 3 sobre openclassrooms](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/le-moteur-de-templates-twig-1) y he descargado [el codigo que utilise el profesor en su curso](https://github.com/winzou/mooc-symfony/tree/iteration-5) al lado de un proyecto que he creado con `sudo php symfony.phar new Symfony` en /var/www/

Mi pregunta esta simple : ¿Si estan ambas abiertos cual sea el que llamo cuando llamo `http://localhost:8000/Symfony/` que no funciona perfectamente ?

Comment: Podrías verificar en el host de apache http.conf, en virtualhost

Comment: Si un proyecto toma el puero 8000, el otro no podra tomarlo y se producira un error (en el segundo proyecto). Por lo tanto solo puedes conectarte al que tomo ese puerto particular.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Gracias por su commentario. ¿ Entonces como hacer para inciar uno y, despues, el otro o pasar du un proyecto a un otro ?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tienes 2 maneras para tener los 2 proyectos activos.

Primera forma:
- puedes levantar un servidor apache con laragon, wampserver.

- el primer código sigues con el curso igual que lo vienes haciendo.
- el segundo codigo, copias el código fuente que generaste en el curso y lo copias en la carpeta www del servidor apache que instalaste antes. Asi manejarías el un codigo en el puerto 8000 y el otro en el puerto 80.

Segunda forma:
- Copiar el código generado al servidor apache y poner nombres diferentes a las carpetas, utilizar el puerto 80 para las 2 y luego ingresas a las app así:

```
http://localhost/codigo1/
http://localhost/codigo2/
```

Saludos